# Redirect does not work when aura component is embedded in a VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I have an aura component that's embedded in a VF page. The component has a button to redirect to an external URL.

When I click the button while previewing the VF page , I get the following error.
e.force:navigateToURL used in .js gives the following error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setParams')] Failing descriptor: {c:cmp1$controller$navigate}.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume your Aura component is embedded in your VF page using lightning out.

As per the docs, `force:navigateToURL` is supported in `Lightning Experience, the Salesforce mobile app, and Aura-based Experience Builder site`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation

e.g. in  `var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");`, `urlEvent` is undefined.

Is there any reason you're not just using VF technology to redirect?

Comment: I used lightning:navigation instead as recommended.navigate gotourl: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var navLink = cmp.find("navlink");
        var pageRef = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            "attributes": {
                "url": "https://salesforce.com"
            },
        };
        
        navLink.navigate(pageRef, true);
        
    }   still it does not redirect